# firefox asks me to download json file containing the search results each time google

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have flashgot plugin running in firefox, each time i google, firefox asks me to download a json file containing the search results, i don't know if this is a firefox issue or flashgot or what!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not Ubuntu-related, it happens to me when running Windows too. It happens when Google's instant search becomes unavailable and you have press enter to search. In other words, it's not you or your computer's/browser's fault.

Comment: what to do about it? disable instant search?

Comment: If you would like to, but at least for me this does not happen consistently enough to do that.